# How to increase the number of vmware.log files?

Tags: vmware-server

Is there any way to increase the number of vmware.log files for a given VM (Vmware Server 1.0.4, host: SLES 10)?
Problem is, that one of our VMs crashes every now and then, and I can only see the four log files vmware.log, vmware-0.log, vmware-1.log and vmware-2.log each of which contains records starting after the crash when trying to boot. So I have no information of what happened before the crash.

Thanks,
Ingo

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this can be done with Server but can be done with ESX.